# moving a file from local machine to cluster

Tags: linux

So I know this will sound very simple, because I'm sure it is. I know when you want to move a file you can use cp or mv in a linux terminal to move from one directory to another. My problem is how do you do it when you want to move a file from your local machine to say a cluster.

To access the cluster, I ssh into it and I have a directory there. Ive tried the absolute filepaths, but that clearly wouldnt work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the `scp` command:

`scp \path\to\your\file.txt user@cluster_address:\path\in\cluster`

then it asks you for the password, which is the same as the one for `ssh`.

Another option is that you can also mount the directory of the cluster machine using `sshfs` and then you can normaly do `cp` and `mv` in the mounted directory.

Comment: Thank youuuu. The nice people at stackoverflow save me yet again!

Comment: What about going in the other direction, is it the same command essentially?

Comment: Yes it is essentially the same. You give the path of the file in the remote computer, and give the target on you local computer.